# ListAdapter OnClickListener not being called

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have a `listactivity` with a `customlistadapter` and the onclick listner is not being called when I touch an item from the list

Below is my oncreate method

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.listitem);
                List<AvailableFeatures> listIntfeats = VehicleAssetsDB.GetAvailableFeatures(2);
                CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(this, listIntfeats);
                ListAdapter = ca;
   }
```

Below is my onlistitemclick listener

```
protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
   System.Console.Writeline("test");
    }
```

but when I select an item from the list nothing happens.

Thanks

Comment: change `System.Console.Writeline("test");` `to Log.d("tag", "test");`  then look in logcat

Comment: that did not fix the problem

Comment: where are you assigning your click listener?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are setting as your content view, it seems like you are trying to set the View for each ListItem there, but that should be handled by your adapter in `GetView`. A simple test here works just fine:

```
public class Activity1 : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        var stupidStuff = new[] {"One", "Two", "Three"};
        ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, stupidStuff);
    }

    protected override void OnListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item {0} clicked", position + 1);
    }
}
```